# How to search an sql lite database with python and print out the result in my ide?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to develop a method whereby it will allow the user to search by a chosen field and value eg. SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_field = 'value'.

It executes just fine in SQL lite but when I bring it into my IDE nothing is printing out.  Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sqlite doc keywords page](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

> **'keyword'**     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.

Suggest not quoting `{field}` in the queries.

Comment: that worked, thanks!